# After using Act of Treason and Cloudshift, does a creature re-enter the battlefield under my control?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If player A has a creature, and then on player B's turn, he/she uses [Act of Treason](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Act%20of%20Treason) on it, and then [Cloudshift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cloudshift), does that card, once it has been cloudshift-ed, return to the battlefield under the control of player B, and thus, not return to A after B's turn has finished?

My thinking is that the card will be under player B's control until the end of the game/ or until the creature in question has been put into the graveyard or removed from play - because, Act of Treason states that you 'gain control of target creature until the end of turn' but cloudshift states that you 'exile target creature you control, then return that card to the battlefield under your control.'.

Any thoughts? Can this be done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It works just as you hope.

Previous "flicker" effects returned the target to play "under its owner's control".  Cloudshift returns it to play "under your control".

Act of Treason gave you control of the creature, making it a valid target for Cloudshift.  Cloudshift returns it into play under your control, and with no memory of its previous life as either the opponent's creature, or of having had Act of Treason cast on it.  It's yours for keeps, or at least until the game ends or another control-changing effect takes place...

> 611.2a A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability lasts as long as stated by the spell or ability creating it (such as “until end of turn”). If no duration is stated, it lasts until the end of the game.

Comment: Also note, obviously the reverse is true. If your opponent has a Cloudshift of their own they can prevent your Act of Treason from resolving…

Comment: @ghoppe how would the cloud shift save it from the act of treason? Act of Treason goes on the stack, then cloud shift goes on top. As could shift resolves the creature is exiled and then immediately returned to the battle field. This means that when Act of Treason resolves, the creature is still a valid target.

Comment: @Pow-Ian [CR 400.7](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/TCG/Article.aspx?x=magic/rules) “An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.” There are seven listed exceptions to the rule, one of them (400.7g) allows Cloudshift to bring the card back. But none of the exceptions are applicable to Act of Treason. The creature initially targeted by Act of Treason (remember, targets are selected when casting the spell, not upon resolution) is not the same creature that has returned from the Exile zone.

Comment: Since Act of Treason no longer has a legal target, it fails to resolve.

Comment: That is an interesting interpretation. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Yes this works.  Any of the flickering mechanics allow stolen creatures to become your creatures permanently.  Going into the exile will reset the creature that is now yours.

This also works well with cards like Simic Manipulator.  Where you can steal their creatures and get counters to steal more creatures.

Comment: Not true: almost all 'flicker' effects before AVR specifically returned the card to play under its _owner's_ control.  Momentary Blink returns the card under its owner's control, as does Flickerwisp, as do Oblivon Ring and Fiend Hunter, as does Obzedat (returning _itself_ to play under its owner's control).  Avacyn Restored's flicker mechanics are the exception but _definitely_ not the rule.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Though, that means the owner of the card can use a flicker effect to take back a card that's been taken by some other means.