# When someone dies who controls a permanent but does not own it, what happens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

In a multiplayer game, if I were to give someone a permanent with [Donate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=15168) and they were to die while controlling that permanent, then would I get that permanent back? Or would the permanent get put into a graveyard?

I am specifically wondering for [Celestial Dawn](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=106639) but I figure it would be the same with any other permanent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get your permanent back.

> 800.4. Unlike two-player games, multiplayer games can continue after one or more players have left the game.
>
> 800.4a. When a player leaves the game, all objects (see rule 109) owned by that player leave the game, **any effects which give that
>   player control of any objects or players end**, and all spells and
>   abilities controlled by that player on the stack cease to exist. Then,
>   if there are any objects still controlled by that player, those
>   objects are exiled. This is not a state-based action. It happens as
>   soon as the player leaves the game. If the player who left the game
>   had priority at the time he or she left, priority passes to the next
>   player in turn order who’s still in the game.

Check out this related question for some more info: [In Magic free-for-all multiplayer, what happens when someone dies?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5463/in-magic-free-for-all-multiplayer-what-happens-when-someone-dies?rq=1)

Comment: @colin D.  What if the player who died was the one who cast the permanant with say... Knowledge pool

Comment: @SamIam I am not completely sure what you are asking, but I believe it would get exiled. `Example: Alex casts Bribery, which reads, “Search target opponent’s library for a creature card and put that card onto the battlefield under your control. Then that player shuffles his or her library,” targeting Bianca. Alex puts Wall of Wood onto the battlefield from Bianca’s library. If Bianca leaves the game, Wall of Wood also leaves the game. If, instead, Alex leaves the game, Wall of Wood is exiled.`

Comment: @SamIam Knowledge Pool says the cards are exiled. So the cards are exiled. I would think.

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen I think he is referring to the card that knowledge pool lets you pay without paying its mana cost. So the situation of someone controlling a card they do not own, but also having no 'control changing effect' that can end.

Comment: @SamIam: The wording of 800.4a explains this: `Then, if there are any objects still controlled by that player, those objects are exiled.` Basically you undo any existing control changing functions that give that player control, if they still control something then that object gets exiled.

Comment: So then how about a creature that has been cloud shift controlled  (http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/11495/after-using-act-of-treason-and-cloudshift-does-a-creature-re-enter-the-battlefi)? Would that card be exiled or returned? It is a **new** permanent after it re-enters right?

Comment: @Pow-Ian Exiled. Wording is very similar to the `Bribery` example above.